# Files with different headers to copy data in azure dwh table

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am new to the Azure Data Warehouse and Azure Data factory V2.

I Have a folder With 10 files in azure blob, Each file is having different headers but there will be a common 5 headers in all files.

**Things I have tried,**

Created 10 linked servers to the files and using copy data task moved the data to the specific tables.
But I required only 5 columns from those tables

**Question**

Is there any way that I can have a table with 5 columns and a dynamic file connection to load data from 5 files.

*Example:*
File1 : 10 headers
File2 : 11 headers
File3 : 7 headers
.
.
.
.
File10 : 15 headers

There will be a common of 5 columns in these files and that data has to be loaded common Table with 5 columns.

Answer (score 2):

When you create external tables in Azure SQL Data Warehouse with Polybase, they can either point to an individual file or a set of files as long as they in the same folder and in the same format.

**Individual file**

```
WTIH (
    DATA_SOURCE = yourDataSource,
    LOCATION = N'/input/file1.txt',
    FILE_FORMAT = yourFileFormat,
    ...
    etc
```

**Folder**

```
WTIH (
    DATA_SOURCE = yourDataSource,
    LOCATION = N'/input/',
    FILE_FORMAT = yourFileFormat,
    ...
    etc
```

So what you could do is create an external table for each file.  The external tables are only metadata structures, the data doesn't actually exist in the database.
These tables must include all columns for each table.  Then create a `UNION` statement over the five tables, selecting the five columns only and use a `CTAS` to import the data into the database:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourTable
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM externalTable1

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM externalTable2

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM externalTable3

etc
....
```

I probably would not use Data Factory as Polybase can do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt below idea:

1.Use [LookUp Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to grab the fileName list stored in your specific azure blob storage container or other paths. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity).

2.Use [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to loop the output of LookUp Activity`[@activity('MyLookupActivity').output]`.

3.Inside the ForEach Activity, use copy activity and configure the source blob storage dataset path as  `specific containerName/dynamic fileName`.(Like the solution in this case:[when try to add dynamic file name (linked server) in azure data factory V2 error encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337163/when-try-to-add-dynamic-file-name-linked-server-in-azure-data-factory-v2-error/56338953#56338953))

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @wBob that Polybase can handle this for you. As an alternative, however, you could use Azure Data Factory Data Flow to process all the files and select just the 5 columns you want, then output those results to a blob sink. Then use the blob for Polybase, which would simplify your Polybase requirements, or use an ADF Copy activity to write them to your SQLDW. There are lots of options in this space.