# when try to add dynamic file name (linked server) in azure data factory V2 error encountered

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am new to the Azure Data factory V2 and blob storage.
When try to add the file connection(linked server) in copy data from blob storage dynamically the following error is encountered while trying to map the columns by importing the schema from file

***"Failed to convert the value in 'container' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.."***

**I tried:**

used static parameters and assign the static parameters to the linked connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my working steps:

1.Configuration of Azure Blob Storage Source DataSet:

[image]

parameters:

[image]

2.Configuration of Azure Blob Storage Sink DataSet:

[image]

3.Configuration of Copy Activity,you could modify the value of parameters here:

[image]

4.Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey JayGong, happy for your contribution here. can you explain the step 2 in your answer. this will help for me

Comment: @Smart003 Hi,any questions about steps2 in my answer. Just configure the destination of files in sink dataset/